# Swift memory leak when iterating array of Errors

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, memory-leaks

I'm relatively new to Swift, so I hope I'm not asking a stupid question.

I have some code that instantiates an array of type `Error`, which will later be iterated and printed to the console. When running this code through Instruments using the "Leaks" instrument, it shows a leak of `_SwiftNativeNSError`. If I change the array type from `[Error]` to `[Any]`, the leak disappears, even though it is still actually holding an object conforming to `Error`. The leak is not reproducible with any other data types or protocols that I've tried.

Here's some sample code:

```
class myLeak {
  lazy var errors = [Error]()
    enum err: Error {
        case myFirstError
    }

    func doSomething() {

        errors.append(err.myFirstError)
        for error in errors {
            print(String(describing: error))
        }
    }
}
// call with let myleak = myLeak(); myleak.doSomething()
```

Calling the doSomething() function immediately creates a leak. Switching `[Error]()` to `[Any]()` resolves the leak, but I'm not happy with this as a solution without understanding the underlying problem. The problem is also solved by changing `[Error]()` to my enum implementing the `Error` protocol: `[err]()`. I've also tried creating my own custom protocol just to prove if this is being caused specifically by `Error`, and I'm only able to reproduce the problem when using `Error`; my own custom protocol did not exhibit this behaviour.

Originally, my code used a `forEach` loop to iterate the array, but I then tried re-writing it to use a standard `for` loop in case the closure in `forEach` was causing the issue, but this didn't work.

I'm suspicious that this may be a Swift bug (in which case, I will open an issue for it), but there's also a chance that I'm missing a key piece of understanding. If what I'm doing is bad practice, I'd like to understand why.

Comment: Copied your code and added deinit to `myLeak` class to check if deist getting called. Clearly its getting called so I dont see any leak because of `myLeak`

Comment: I've added an explanation for it. I guess the problem is due to `Error`.

Comment: I've added an update.

Comment: @LorenzoB Thanks - I did find that bug logged, but although it seems related, this seemed like a slightly different case, as that had to do specifically with an Optional Error. I agree it definitely looks related, and I cited that bug in the radar I filed. Thanks so much for following up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

After speaking with Joe Groff, an Apple engineer, this is the bug you could have encountered: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6536

**Original Answer**

I've played a bit with your code and I think the problem is due to `Error` type.
In fact, taking the code by Josh, you can find a different behaviour if you use `Error` or `MyError` as the type of your array.

I guess the problem arises since the `deinit` call is not forwarded to `CustomObject` since `Error` is just a protocol and it's not aware of the underlying class. While, `MyError` is. We can wait for other people to have clarifications on this behaviour.

Just for simplicity, I'm using a Playground here. See that I'm not even trying to print the error value.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var errors: [Error] = [] // change to MyError to see it working

    enum MyError: Error {
        case test (CustomObject)
    }

    class CustomObject {
        deinit {
            print("deiniting")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let testerror = MyError.test(CustomObject())
        errors.append(testerror)
        errors.removeAll()
    }    
}

do {
    let viewController = ViewController()
    // just for test purposes ;)
    viewController.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. In your opinion, would you say this is a bug, or expected behaviour? Your explanation about the deinit call not being forwarded makes good sense.

Comment: @CPR I think you can open a radar. But, I'm not sure to say the truth.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. I've already filed a radar, so will await the response.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it looks like the `String(describing)` statement is causing the string to retain the error, which is just weird.  Here is how I can tell: I created an associated object that prints out when its being deinitialized.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var errors = [Error]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        class CustomObject {
            deinit {
                print("deiniting")
            }
        }
        enum MyError: Error {
            case test (CustomObject)
        }
        let testerror = MyError.test(CustomObject())
        errors.append(testerror)
        for error in errors {
            //print(String(describing: error))
        }
        errors.removeAll()
    }

}
```

When the print doesn't run, sure enought he associated object is deinitialized at when the error is removed from the array and the output is:

```
deiniting
```

Uncomment the print and the output becomes:

```
test(CustomObject #1 in stack.ViewController.viewDidLoad() -> ())
```

At first I thought it was the print that's the problem but If I refactor to:

```
errors.forEach{print($0)}
```

I get the output:

```
test(CustomObject #1 in stack.ViewController.viewDidLoad() -> ())
deiniting
```

But if I change it to:

```
errors.map {String(describing:$0)}.forEach{print($0)}
```

Then deinit is no longer called:

```
test(CustomObject #1 in stack.ViewController.viewDidLoad() -> ())
```

Weirdness. Maybe file a [radar](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I completely overlooked the String(describing:) statement as a possible source of the error. Good to get some confirmation that there's nothing inherently wrong with my code. I'll accept this as solution later, but will leave it open for now in case anyone is able to offer additional insight. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've added an explanation for it. I guess the problem is due to `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was Fixed in Xcode 9.3.