# swift: case error in switch

Tags: swift, switch-statement

```
var values = [[Double]]()
values.insert([-1, -1], at: 0)
print(values[0]) // [-1.0, -1.0]
switch values[0] {
case [-1.0, -1.0]: // error here
    print("ok")
default:
    break
}
```

I put in switch exactly the same as what I get in print function. Error is:

> Expression pattern of type '[Double]' cannot match values of type
>   '[Double]'.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: The reason is that Array does not (yet) conform to  Equatable, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377761/swift-equality-operator-on-nested-arrays for a similar issue.

Comment: @MartinR you are faster than me :) Just to have a confirmation I'm no doing it wrong, can you take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904498/swift-memory-leak-when-iterating-array-of-errors/47907118#47907118

Comment: If all your inner arrays have 2 elements, then you could define an array of tuples instead: `var values = [(Double, Double)]()` and then the pattern matching works.

Comment: Or you can create your own struct and make it conform to equatable. This also can improve readability of your code. @MartinR

Comment: This works: switch (values[1][0], values[1][1]) {
        case (-1.0, -1.0):

Comment: @Anton: ... but crashes at runtime if `values[1]` has less than 2 elements.

Comment: In my case there always will be 2 elements. Otherwise 'guard' would help. Thanks, anyway!